# Google chrome extension messes up regex global flag

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

Am I doing something wrong, or is it Google Chromes fault ?
Using non-capture and capture groups has the same effect as without them.

RegExr shows the first expected result. http://regexr.com?30mjo

```
var text = 'startdate: 123456, enddate: 789012';
var unix = text.match(/(?:start|end)date: (\d+)/g);
console.log(unix);
```

**Actual result**

```
["startdate: 123456", "enddate: 789012"]
```

**Expected result**

```
["123456", "789012"] or  
["startdate: 123456", "123456", "enddate: 789012", "789012"]
```

Comment: It seems like the `g` flag is making it act weird. without it the first result is returned fine. I will investigate more.

Comment: maybe add a comma after `(\d+)` when using `g`? like `... (\d+),/g);`? although really that should not make a difference....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the spec says that it should work this way.

Relevant line is

`4. Let matchStr be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of result with 
argument "0"`

on page 146 of [the ecmascript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) where `result` is the array you get back from calling `exec`.

I've been unable to find a way to make this work, other than manually calling exec and collecting the results like so:

```
var regex = /(?:start|end)date: (\d+)/g;
var text = 'startdate: 123456, enddate: 789012';

var result;
var unix = [];

while(result = regex.exec(text)){    
    unix.push(result[1]);
}

console.log(unix);
```

Comment: Using this alternate solution works, but I figured I didnt the global flag for this since it was looping. However that was a major mistake! It turned into an endless loop, where it kept adding the first match over and over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing something wrong.

What about this?

```
/((?:start|end)date: (\d+))/g
```

Comment: So can you please explain how to get the non-capturing group to work?

Comment: why don't you just do:
`/(start|end)date: (\d+)/g`

and only use the 2nd (or even numbered) matching group? This should work unless start-/end- date is optional. Just loop over the results and use `i+=2` for your increment, grab groups 2, 4, 6 etc...?